# "Reference to uninitialized collection"

Tags: plsql

I want to display all dates in output occurring between two dates which are given as input to package.

This is my package:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_NETORSONTECH
    AS
      TYPE ARRAY1 IS TABLE OF DATE;
      PROCEDURE PRINT_DATES (START_DATE VARCHAR2, END_DATE VARCHAR2);
    END PKG_NETORSONTECH;
```

this is my package body

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_NETORSONTECH
AS

  FUNCTION CALC_DATES (START_DATE DATE, END_DATE DATE)
  RETURN ARRAY1
  AS
  A1 ARRAY1;
  COUNTER NUMBER := 1;
  X DATE;
  BEGIN
  X := START_DATE;
  LOOP
  A1(COUNTER) := X;
  X := X + 1;
  COUNTER := COUNTER + 1;
  EXIT WHEN X = END_DATE;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN A1;
  END CALC_DATES;

  PROCEDURE PRINT_DATES (START_DATE VARCHAR2, END_DATE VARCHAR2)
  AS
  A2 ARRAY1;
  BEGIN

  A2 := CALC_DATES(TO_DATE(START_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE(START_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY'));

  FOR X IN A2.FIRST..A2.LAST
  LOOP
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(A2(X));
  END LOOP;

  END PRINT_DATES;

END PKG_NETORSONTECH;
```

This is my execution input:

```
EXEC PKG_NETORSONTECH.PRINT_DATES('09/APR/2010', '12/DEC/2010');
```

When I executes this code it gives following error

```
   EXEC PKG_NETORSONTECH.PRINT_DATES('09/APR/2010', '12/DEC/2010')
    Error report -
    ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection
    ORA-06512: at "BMAHAJAN.PKG_NETORSONTECH", line 13
    ORA-06512: at "BMAHAJAN.PKG_NETORSONTECH", line 26
    ORA-06512: at line 1
    06531. 00000 -  "Reference to uninitialized collection"
    *Cause:    An element or member function of a nested table or varray
               was referenced (where an initialized collection is needed)
               without the collection having been initialized.
    *Action:   Initialize the collection with an appropriate constructor
               or whole-object assignment.
```

Comment: Just an observation for `A2 := CALC_DATES(TO_DATE(START_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE(START_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY'));` - 1) You are using both start dates here, and 2) you are using date format as `dd/mm/yyyy` whereas the data you are sending is in `dd/mmm/yyyy` format.

Answer (score 1):

Before using a collection variable (or any `TYPE` for that matter), you have to initialize it by calling its constructor.

In here, before you start the loop with A1, you have to call the constructor by -

```
A1 := new Array1();
```

This creates an empty array with 0 elements and assigns it to the variable. The new keyword is optional.

Since this is a nested table type and not an associative array, you also have to call `.EXTEND` for the collection based on how many elements there are in the collection.

If you know there are going to be x number of elements in the collection, you can do -

```
A1.EXTEND(x);
```

If you don't know the number of elements, you can call -

```
A1.EXTEND;
```

inside the loop to add a new element into the collection, for every iteration of that loop.